# React Native -- cannot start because HTTP server already being used by another WebSocket server

Tags: javascript, websocket, react-native, archlinux

I'm running npx react-native start/npx react-native run-android, and everything builds fine; however, the app cannot start a server properly.  This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: The HTTP/S server is already being used by another WebSocket server
    at new WebSocketServer (.../node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:83:15)
    at Object.attachToServer (.../node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/messageSocket.js:93:15)
    at Object.runServer [as func] (.../node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/runServer.js:127:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (.../@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:164:9)
```

I've tried killing all react-native related processes, and even if I reboot the system, this error still persists.  Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by removing the dependency @react-native-community/cli-platform-android altogether, but I'm not completely satisfied with the solution because I have to run npx react-native start and npx react-native run-android separately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `processTicksAndRejections()` method is trying to set up its own WebSocketServer instance to do its work, rather than using one that's already set up.  Your error message means that you

1. already have an http/s server going
2. already have a websocket server set up on it
3. you're trying to set up another websocket server on that existing http/s server.

If you were trying to run two server processes on the same port, a different error message would show up.